# HTML String to indented code

Tags: php, html, string, indentation

I have a string I get from crawling this website: https://www.exploit-db.com

In an specific exploit I get the code:

```
$code = $crawler2->filterXPath('//div[@id="container"]/pre->each(function ($nodes) {
                return  $nodes->text();
                    });
```

Then I print it:

```
print $code[0];
```

And I got it without format.

How to print indented, in a nice way¿?

Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DOMDocument method [saveXML](http://php.net/manual/bg/domdocument.savexml.php) and the formatOutput = 1 param.

Comment: This is what I do: 
$code[3]->formatOutput = 1;
     print $code[3];

I get the same output.